# best way to parse currency string safety?

Tags: java, string, currency

On server I accept String as argument. This String represents money.

It may be (for example)

```
0  
12  
12,  
12,34  
,12
```

Now I pare it like this:

```
long centAmount = (long) (NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse(outSum).doubleValue() * 100)
```

am afraid that I can lost cent somewhere.

Please advise how to rewrite my code.

Comment: If you're always going to use `.` as the decimal separator, you should probably use `Locale.US` instead. I'd also suggest parsing it as a `BigDecimal` rather than as a `double`...

Comment: Can you be clearer about just what is going wrong?

Comment: I agree with Jon; try to leave the "floating point numbers" out of the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `(long)` this truncates the number.  This means that `0.999999999999999` will be truncated to `0` which will lose you a cent here and there.  A better approach is to use rounding.

```
double input = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse(outSum).doubleValue();
long centAmount = Math.round(input * 100);
```

This will work for values up to $70 trillion.  If you need to store larger amount accurately you will need to use BigDecimal & BigInteger.

One of the advantages of using BigDecimal is that it will remind you when you should use rounding (not always but it is less error prone if you are unsure)  The downside is that the code is far more cumbersome.

if you use BigDecimal you can do this

```
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) df.parseObject(outSum);
BigDecimal bd100 = bd.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))
                     .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
long centAmount = bd100.longValue();
```

---

Adding a simple example of why BigDecimal doesn't solve all problems, but it does hid them.

```
    BigDecimal add = new BigDecimal("1.00")
              .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
              .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(3)).add(new BigDecimal("0.01"));
    System.out.println(add);
    double add2 = 1.0 / 3 * 3 +  0.01;
    System.out.println(add2);
```

This prints

```
1.00
1.01
```

Which one is more error prone, you could argue either way (and this is likely to be based on your team as to which they find less error prone), but which one is harder to understand what it is trying to do?

The problem I have with BigDecimal is the black&white assessment that `double` is flawed and BigDecimal will fix all you problems when actually, you get all the same problems but with BigDecimal they can be harder to spot, so you might never know you have a problem.

With double, if you see `1.0999999999999998` you think, that doesn't look right, but with BigDecimal, you might see `1.00` and think that looks ok.

Comment: So you are concerned about rounding errors, but you suggest to first parse to a floating point number?

Comment: @Jägermeister the `Math.round` will sort out any floating point error.

Comment: @Jägermeister Like I said, this is fine up to $70 trillion which is fine in most cases.  Many assume that rounding errors are unknowable or evil or bad luck ??, but actually in most real world cases they just require you to use rounding correctly (whether you think this is error prone or not is another question)  The problem I have with BigDecimal is that the problem is not solved, just far less likely, and yet there is a tax on all your coding (if we ignore the performance difference). You still get cases where you need to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Jägermeister added the BigDecimal version for completeness.

Comment: @All: if you think that I am talking nowsense; just run this little snippet here: `double a = 0.5; double b = 0.4; double c = 0.1; double one = 1;  System.out.println("surprise: " + one* (a -b -c)); ` So, the point is: certain numbers can **not** be expressed using the binary number system. So, if you are dealing with fractions of money, **NEVER** ever use floating point to deal with them.

Comment: @Jägermeister try 1 / 7 * 7 - 1 with BigDecimal without rounding you get the same conclusion, BTW this is fine using `double`

Comment: @Jägermeister I note you didn't write the same in BigDecimal because then it would have been much longer and more error prone. ;)

Comment: Floating point/doubles shouldn't be used for currency values. Yes you might sometimes be able to use them safely but I guarantee someone who comes along and doesn't know what they are doing will break the world if you let them.

Comment: @TimB I can make the same guarantee about BigDecimal. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Not at all. People don't realize that 0.2+0.8 != 1 and that breaks things in all sorts of subtle and horrible ways

Comment: @TimB similarly people don't realise that `new BigDecimal(0.2).add(new BigDecimal(0.8)).compareTo(new BigDecimal(1.0)) != 0` or `new BigDecimal("0.2").add(new BigDecimal("0.8")).equals(new BigDecimal("1"))` is `false` and a host of other problems with using BigDecimal.

Comment: @TimB The difference is that `double` is much simpler to code, and it looks really wrong when you have a bug, but when you use BigDecimal it is harder to code and harder to spot when you have an error because it still looks right.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Only because you're using a different scale for "1", use "1.0" instead and you will get the correct result. Using doubles instead you can get actually wrong values coming out of calculations - particularly once the errors have had a chance to compound each other for a while.

Comment: @TimB So once you understand the library and it's quirks, you can use it correctly, but you still end up with code which is bloated and slower.  Once you understand how double works and it's quirks you get cleaner/faster code.